# How to use variables in components with Gatsby Graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using gatsby with Wordpress, I have a component that should load some posts according to a variable category, the idea is to be able to use that component in several places, but I have not been able to find the way to do it.

This is the component

```js
import * as React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import './styles/bloque1.css';

const Bloque1 = ({Titulo, PostID}) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
   query {
     allWpPost(
       limit: 3
       filter: {categories: {nodes: {elemMatch: {databaseId: {eq: ${PostID} }}}}}
     ) {
       nodes {
         title
         slug
         date
         featuredImage {
          node {
            sourceUrl
            localFile {
              childImageSharp {
                gatsbyImageData
              }
            }
          }
        }
       }
     }
   }
   `)

  return (
    <div className="ct-blq-1">
      <h2>{Titulo}</h2>
      {data.allWpPost.nodes.map(element => 
      <div className="container-img">
        <GatsbyImage image={getImage(element.featuredImage.node.localFile)} alt=""  className="img"/>
        <div className="blq-1-item">
          <Link to="https://www.valoraanalitik.com/2022/04/12/j-p-morgan-rebajo-recomendacion-adr-bancolombia/"
            rel="bookmark" title={element.title}>
            <div className="nota-titulo">
              <h3>{element.title}</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="nota-tiempo">
              <time>{element.date}</time>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Bloque1
```

I am looking for a way to use the PostID in {databaseId: {eq: ${PostID} }}

```js
const Page = () => (
    <section id="page">
        <main>

            <Bloque1 Titulo="Noticias Destacadas" PostID="2"/>

            <Bloque2 />
        </main>
    </section>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use dynamic variables in a static query (hence the name). It's a [known limitation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/#known-limitations):

> - `useStaticQuery` does not accept variables (hence the name “static”), but can be used in any component, including pages
> - Because of how queries currently work in Gatsby, we support only a single instance of `useStaticQuery` in a file

That said, depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can use a [page query or using a template](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/). To use variables in page queries, you need to provide them using context, not via `props` as you were trying to when you generate the page. If you are not generating page using `gatsby-node.js`, you can always fetch all posts (`allWpPost`) and filter them using JavaScript with the provided `postID`.

There are a lot of implementation details missing to provide a full snippet but you can adapt your WordPress structure to this tutorial: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/